# Bank Statement for UK Visa before the studying fee payment

Tags: visas, uk, russia

I am Russian and going to apply for UK Short-term study Visa for studying during few weeks in language school in UK. 
Don't I get the refusal if I firstly will make the bank statement, and only after that will pay study fee, avia tickets and so on.

Doing this way I want to show I have enough money, but after payments maybe not so much.

**UPD:**

In case you have enough money for paying study fee but no more, you have two "action sequence":

*First action sequence:*

1. **Make a bank statement**
2. Then transfer full payment to Language School
3. Get invitation from school
4. Apply for a visa with "not updated"
   bank statement where you had enough money

*Second action sequence:*

1. Transfer full payment to Language School
2. Get invitation from school
3. **Make a bank statement**
4. Apply for a visa bank statement where you might have not enough money as you transferred a lot for a study fee

Q: what to choose? Obviously first in less risky but is it legal?

Comment: The instructions for UK visas quite specifically tell you *not* to make travel bookings before your visa is granted (and I'd imagine this applies to study fees too).

Comment: @brhans it is not possible, the visa invitation letter is provided to me only after full payment of study fee. So it is still a question may I make bank statement before the payment in order to have more money on the bank account

Comment: @brhans what is the document where it is written ?

Comment: [Visitor: supporting documents guide](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf). See section 4 at the end for the list of things they tell you not to send.

Comment: Why don't print out a bank statement for your application BEFORE withdrawing the money to pay the school? You can get the documents from the school within a few days of making payment and add to your application, no?

Comment: @MusoniusRufus You got the idea. I've updated the question. Question is: is it legal to apply for UK visa bank statement which actually is not valid anymore as after you made a bank statement you have already paid for the school , so ACTUALLY you have already less money

Comment: You are thinking too much. UK embassy does not expect that the bank statement you send to them is accurate to the last second. That is why they accept bank statements up to over a month old. Because the normal human being has transactions in their account every week. [Over analysis and resulting paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis)

Comment: @MusoniusRufus funny thing about analysis paralysis :) this just a question from my client who actually already in UK , but still I think it is reasonable question

Comment: It appears that you think that you think there is a particular threshold the balance of your bank statement must exceed to show that you're rich enough to be worthy of getting a visa. [That is not how it works.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: @HenningMakholm actually there is a threshold. Like 60 pounds per day or smith like this. But it is not a public info. I've read the great answer that you are referring.

Comment: @pure_true: That figure sounds like a guideline for what a traveler _should be prepared to spend_ during the trip. It is not a mindless figure that will be compared to a bank statement balance on a random day.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a bit of a Catch 22… If you don’t pay the fees for the program and have the documents from the school to prove your eligibility and admission, then your visa application may be refused. And you need to include financial documents that show you have sufficient funds available. You do not need to purchase flight tickets in advance; indeed, you are directed to wait until a visa decision before making those arrangements.

If finances are at issue, you may want to postpone application until you have enough money put aside to pay the school fees, airfare, and all other expenses (accommodation, maintenance).

Comment: You didn't get the idea of the question. In case you have enough money for paying study fee but no more, you have two "action sequence" :

1 action sequence: 
Make a bank statement -> Then transfer full payment to Language School -> Get invitation from school -> Apply for a visa with "not updated" bank statement where you had enough money

2 action sequence:
Transfer full payment to Language School -> Get invitation from school -> Make a bank statement - > Apply for a visa bank statement where you might have not enough money as you transfer a lot for a study fee

Q: what to choose?

Comment: @pure_true: If paying the school means that you wouldn't afford to take your trip, then you _cannot afford it_, full stop.